# Image Navigation Slider Android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, slider

I want to replicate the iOS camera roll slider bar on Android.
The functionality would be to show a fixed number of thumbnail, but being able to slide trough all the images.

The result would be this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two layouts: one for putting the thumbnail views at runtime and one with a custom seek bar. Place the seek bar layout on top of the thumbnail layout. Make the progress bar transparent and use your current thumbnail as the thumb of your seek bar. Set the max value of the seek bar to the number of pages - 1. Make sure both your layouts are the same width.
Add an OnSeekBarChangeListener to your seek bar:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // Retrieve the thumbnail for the page
    // progress = page id, since the max value of the seek bar is restricted to the number of pages
    Bitmap thumbnail = getThumbnailForPage(int progress)
    if (thumbnail != null) {
        seekBar.setThumb(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), thumbnail));
    }

    // Change the view pager to the page with id = progress
}
```

Create your ImageViews of the page thumbnails at runtime and add them to the thumbnail layout. Your seek bar layout should be on the foreground, otherwise you will not be able to click the bar and it will not detect progress changes.

Answer (score 0):

You Should combine a horizontal SCROLLVIEW and a LINEARLAYOUT and a GRIDVIEW to achieve what you want! put grid view in linearlayout and put the linear layout in the horizontal scroll view;

then when setting adapter! count the number of data! after that you should calculate the desired width to show all your items! for example you want to show 8 item! each width is 100dp . so the desired width would be 800dp! then you should add these lines of code

```
yourGridView.setNumColumns(8);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
yourGridView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

dnt forget to set the width of the linear layout as WRAP_CONTENT in the xml!

*** IMPORTANT NOTE ***
as i know, by doing this, gridview can't garbage collection because Scroll View doesn't support such a thing and your grid view nested in it! so dnt use this method for lots of images or you will get HEAP SIZE error!